# Select all a links without h tags

Tags: html, css

I want to underline all links but not if the links are h1,h2 and so on.
here is a simple css:

```
#heatmapthemead-the-content-container .entry-content a {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

This underlines all links including h1,h2,h3
when I use :not selector it doesn't work and also h1,h2 stay underlined

```
#heatmapthemead-the-content-container .entry-content a:not(h1,h2,h3) {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

I use also !important :

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 a {
text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

But h1,h2 links stay underlined.
Does anybody have a trick?

Comment: First, start with a CSS selector with the least amount of specificity. Is it necessary to include `#heatmapthemead-the-content-container .entry-content` in the CSS selector? Is it overkill? Will something simpler work, like `h1 a`? Always go with the least amount of specificity as needed. And `!important` is typically used in very specific instances, of which, this situation doesn't appear to qualify.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to make it `!important`. Look at the example below.

```css
a{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

h1 a,
h2 a,
h3 a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1><a href="#">Sample</a></h1>
  <p><a href="#">Sample</a></p>
  <h2><a href="#">Sample</a></h2>
  <div><a href="#">Sample</a></div>
  <h3><a href="#">Sample</a></h3>
</div>
```

You're writing the code in wrong way, write it like

```
h1 a, h2 a, h3 a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

and so on.

And writing like this will make the code more readable, and easier to find your mistake.

```
h1 a,
h2 a,
h3 a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

It not gonna make any difference in the output though.

Comment: FWIW, in this specific example, the `text-decoration: none;` selectors do not have to be after the `text-decoration: underline;` selector as it has a higher specificity. They would only need to come after if they had the same specificity, then the cascade would come into play and whatever was declared last would win out.

Answer (score 0):

Your last example has the right idea and should work if you did it like this:

```
h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `:not`. All you have to do is select the tags but add a next to it, so that it selects the h1s that are a link. By doing the following it should work.

```
h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

To see more click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp)

Comment: Is it possible to simplify this so we don't need to repeat each heading?